# Number of ways getting out of the elevator?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

At the ground floor of a building 6 men and 5 women get into the elevator. The elevator gets up and stops at each floor and stops at the floor 8. In how many ways can the people get out if all men are considered identical and all women are considered identical and it is possible that at one floor no one gets out.

We have 11 people. So are there $8^{11}$ ways?

Comment: There are different conventions for floor numbers. Some people call the ground floor the first floor, some call the floor above that the first floor. You should specify which convention you're using.

Comment: If the people had all been distinguishable, then $8^{11}$ would be correct.

Comment: $8^{11}$ would be the answer (for one of the two floor numbering conventions) if all $8$ people were considered to be distinguishable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. Let $m_i$ and $w_i$ be respectively the number of men and the number of women that get out at floor $i$. Then the desired number of ways is the product of the numbers of the non-negative integer solutions of these two equations:
$$\sum_{i=1}^8 m_i=6\quad\mbox{and}\quad\sum_{i=1}^8 w_i=5.$$
See [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)#Theorem_two) technique.

Comment: No, I mean the number of solutions of the first equation multiplied by the number of solutions of the second equation.

Comment: Ah ok! But how can we calculate that number of solutions?

Comment: @MaryStar See my edit above.

Comment: So for the first equation do we have $\binom{6+8-1}{8-1}$ and the second of $\binom{5+8-1}{8-1}$ ?

Comment: So do we have $\binom{13}{7}\cdot \binom{12}{7}$ ways?

Comment: @MaryStar Yes!!

Comment: Great!! Thank you!! :-)